# How to Retrieve data from DataGridView and Display?

Tags: c#

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

I have a DataGrid located on a form and the button will populate the datagrid with this data. If a Selected Row or Cell were selected, how would I display this data in a textbox or another datagrid? Preferably a Textbox.

Comment: Which data you want to show into a textbox on cell selection?

Comment: Any of the selected data on the datagrid. For example, if a  Row were selected, display just that row in another datagrid. There are only these 4 rows in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample... it works for me

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
                this.pcode = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;

            }
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    // Get reference to button field in the gridview.  
                    LinkButton _singleClickButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
                    string _jsSingle = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
                    e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "hand";
                    e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = _jsSingle;
                }
            }
        }


        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < r.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
                    {
                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(r.UniqueID + "$ctl00", columnIndex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            base.Render(writer);
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "ColumnClick")
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < r.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
                        {
                            r.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes["style"] += "background-color:White;";
                        }
                    }
                }
                selectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                // int selectedColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());
                GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Attributes["style"] += "background-color:Red;";
                TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Text; 

            }
        }
```

Comment: Input this code into the project I already have? Or is this a fresh new project?

Comment: analyse the code see the flow, and implement it in your project